# Finding out when an MySQL user was added?

Tags: mysql

I was just looking through my MySQL user databases (for all the MySQL users in PhpMyadmin) and noticed something exceedingly alarming, a user named darkangel with all permissions. I havent looked in a few weeks but I didnt notice this user last I looked. I need to know asap when this user was created. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check modification date of mysql/user.MYD file

Comment: Ofcorse, I knew I shouldn't have removed the user.... Can I still find out?

Comment: By that I mean, I deleted the user in phpmyadmin, which will probably mean th edit date will have changed

Comment: general log, binary log - is either of them enabled?